# Chain Shape Collision

Tags: box2d, andengine, physics-engine

I am facing new problem by using chain shape. The collision between two chain shape body not happened as like normal body. So this is normal behaviour or am I doing any mistake for this?

Following are the code for this purpose.

```
        ChainShape mChainShape = new ChainShape();
        Vector2[] mVector2 = new Vector2[lineList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < lineList.size(); i++) {
                mVector2[i] = new Vector2(lineList.get(i).getX1()
                                / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT,
                                lineList.get(i).getY1()
                                / PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
        }

        mChainShape.createChain(mVector2);
        FixtureDef mFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        Body mChainBody;
        BodyDef mBodyDef = new BodyDef();
        mBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        mChainBody = mPhysicsWorld.createBody(mBodyDef);
        mFixtureDef.shape = mChainShape;
        mFixtureDef.density = 1f;
        mFixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;
        mFixtureDef.restitution = 0.5f;
        mChainBody.createFixture(mFixtureDef);
        mChainShape.dispose();
```

if I want to create body based on touch coordinates then this thing possible or not?

Please give any guidance in this.

Comment: chain/line geometry cannot collide against chain/line geometry. It is not supported. Try to see if you can use thin rectangles on the dynaimic bodies.

Comment: If I decide to create polygon shape based on touch then how to create it?

Comment: that's not easy to answer. But if you have dynamic chain shapes then you Need to have solid shapes in order to collide with them. e.g. for many situations you need a convex decomposition.

Comment: That I know my friend, but I want only concept about implementation. Only single suggestion become enough for me.

Comment: Sure, you need to use more specific language though. What does "create body based on touch coordinates" mean? Create a body that represents what? The boundary? the shape enclosed by your touch? Not all touches move back to the starting point, you know. How you gonna deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Chain shape collision is not supported in BOX 2D.

But if your body is polygon, you can create a triangular approximation for this and compose your body from b2PolygonShape.

```
b2Vec2 triVerts[3];
// for this example polygon should have "center" point, from that it can be observed around. 
triVerts[0] = b2Vec2(0,0); // center
for(int idx = 1; idx < lineList.size(); idx++)
{
    b2PolygonShape triangle;
    fixtureDef.shape = &triangle;
    // Assumes the vertices are going around
    triVerts[1] = mVector2[idx-1];
    triVerts[2] = mVector2[idx];
    triangle.Set(triVerts,3);
    mChainBody.CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
```

for b2PolygonShape collision will works fine.

Comment: In case anyone's interested... I've added support for chain shape collisions in [my dev branch fork of Box2D](https://github.com/louis-langholtz/Box2D).

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Box2D now includes Chain shapes, but it's in the documentation: https://box2d.org/documentation/md__d_1__git_hub_box2d_docs_collision.html#autotoc_md40